# How delete global window object?

Tags: javascript

My test code:

```
var a = 10

function ab(){
    debugger
 window=null
 alert(window.a)
}

ab();
```

I want to remove access to Window.object

Comment: Good luck with that. I can always get it back. `(function() {window = this; /* do stuff */ })()`

Comment: Is it just the property `a` you want to remove?

Comment: Why do you want to remove `window`?

Comment: In a browser context, you cannot do that.

Comment: Smells like XY problem. Heavily, I'd say.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol what if there is global strict mode enabled?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol—in your comment, `this === window` so why expect `window = this` to do anything (in non–strict mode)?

Comment: @RobG It was a demo, but fair point XD